# html(s) regex validation in xsd file

Tags: regex, xsd

I've written the regex to validate url (it must require http(s)) for my xml schema:

```
^[https?]+://([^/:]+\.[a-z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?(\/.*)?$
```

I'm now trying to avoid all the restriction from https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html. I've came up with this:

```
[https?]+://([^/:]+\.[a-z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?[^>](\/.*)
```

but still got XMLSchemaParseError about invalid regular expression. Could you help me fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid all the restriction from.."? Note to begin with, I don't think `[https?]+` does what you think: it allows any of the chars present between the `[]` in any order from 1 to any amout of times. You probably wanted `https?` (in this strict order, with "s" optional) instead of `[https?]+`

Comment: The `[https?]+` must be turned into `https?` and you do not need to escape `/`. Also, the `/.*` at the end should probably be optional. Try `https?://([^/:]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works, awsome. Thank you a lot. If you'll change your comment into the answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `^` and `$` anchors is a correct step since [XmlSchema regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) is meant to match *the whole string input*, and `^` and `$` are not treated as start/end of the string metacharacters as in most - if not all - other regex flavors.

The `[https?]+` that matches 1 or more `h`, `t`, `p`, `s` or `?` chars must be turned into `https?` to match `http`, an optional `s`.

You do not need to escape `/`, turn `\/` into `/`.

Also, the `/.*` at the end should be optional, add `?` quantifier.

Use

```
https?://([^/:]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?
```

Some usage:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
  <xsd:element name="ElementNameHere">
    <xsd:simpleType>
      <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
        <xsd:pattern value="https?://([^/:]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)? "/> 
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```